# convert markdown text to html table using perl

Tags: html, perl, text, markdown

I'm trying to convert a Markdown text to HTML table with Perl modules. I tried to use Text::Markdown, but it didn't work.

I also tried to use Markdown::Table and follow the documentation: https://metacpan.org/pod/Markdown::Table,
but same thing no result.

Here is my code:

```
use Markdown::Table;

my $markdown = q~
| Id | Name | Role |
+---+---+---+
| 1 | John Smith | Testrole |
| 2 | Jane Smith | Admin |
~;
 
my @tables = Markdown::Table->parse($markdown);
                        
use Data::Dumper;
Core::Global::Logger::debug(Dumper( $tables[0]->get_table ) );
```

Output: [image]

can anyone help about that please ?

Comment: i found it on internet, and i gave it a try, can you suggest a module can do that please ?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::MultiMarkdown maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Text::MultiMarkdown` the original Markdown doesn't support tables. And `Text::Markdown` only supports the orignal syntax.

`Text::MultiMarkdown` has additional features.

- Project Site: https://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/
- Features: https://rawgit.com/fletcher/MultiMarkdown-6-Syntax-Guide/master/index.html

Additional you have to change the table format.

```perl
use v5.10;
use Text::MultiMarkdown qw(markdown);

my $text = q[
| Id | Name | Role |
|---|---|---|
| 1 | John Smith | Testrole |
| 2 | Jane Smith | Admin |
];

# Replace any CRLF/LF line-endings to the native Line-Ending used by Perl
$text =~ s/\R/\n/g;

my $html = markdown($text);

printf "%s\n", $html;
```

will produce

```html
<table>
<col />
<col />
<col />
<thead>
<tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John Smith</td>
        <td>Testrole</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Jane Smith</td>
        <td>Admin</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've tried it but, here is what i get : <pre><code>        | Id | Name | Role |
        |---|---|---|
        | 1 | John Smith | Testrole |
        | 2 | Jane Smith | Admin |
</code></pre>

Comment: @Mons do you have leading spaces in front of your table?

Comment: no, i tried to copy the same table you wrote, and that was the output

Comment: @Mons When you have `<code>` in it, it's a sign you have indented the text by 4 whitespace characters, or a tab. Otherwise i cannot re-produce your output.

Comment: @Mons Could it be that you have Line-Endings problems? For example create the file with Linux file ending LF, but then use a Windows Perl to execute your code? Maybe a `$text =~ s/\R/\n/g;` can help before you call the `markdown()` function?

Comment: tried it but didn't work :,(

Comment: FYI, this code works perfectly fine when I try it as well.

Comment: Interesting, whenever i try it, i get the same output shared, maybe i have a problem with cache, will try to find the problem very soon and let you know!

Comment: Worked as expected, thank you so much @DavidRaab for your help and for your   time, you saved my life <3

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend to use Perl's [Pandoc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pandoc) module, which is a wrapper around [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/), a tool to convert documents from one format to another. For instance,

```
use Pandoc;

my $markdown = q(
Some `standard` **Markdown** _syntax_. Also, a table:

country | capital
--------|---------
France  | Paris
UK      | London
Germany | Berlin);

print pandoc->convert('markdown' => 'html', $markdown);
```

Which outputs:

```html
<p>Some <code>standard</code> <strong>Markdown</strong> <em>syntax</em>. Also, a table:</p>
<table>
<thead>
<tr class="header">
<th>country</th>
<th>capital</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td>France</td>
<td>Paris</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
<td>UK</td>
<td>London</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td>Germany</td>
<td>Berlin</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note that for this to work, you'll have to install Perl's Pandoc module (with `cpanm Pandoc` for instance), as well as the Pandoc program (with `sudo apt install pandoc` on Debian/Ubuntu; see [Installing pandoc](https://pandoc.org/installing.html) for other systems).

---

Regarding the other modules you tried to use:

- [Markdown::Table](https://metacpan.org/pod/Markdown::Table) is a module that aims at helping you parse and manipulate Markdown tables. It does not generate HTML (nor anything besides Markdown for that matter).
- [Text::Markdown](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Markdown) generates HTML from Markdown, but does not support Markdown tables. The syntax of Markdown supported by this module is specified in https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax, and does not include tables.
  Still, this module allows you to write HTML inside your Markdown, which *could* be a workaround, depending on your exact requirements. For instance:

  ```
  use Text::Markdown 'markdown';

  my $markdown = q(
  This _text_ uses **Markdown** `syntax`. Then a table:

  <table>
  <tr><td>country</td><th>capital</th></tr>
  <tr><td>France</td><td>Paris</td></tr>
  <tr><td>UK</td><td>London</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Germany</td><td>Berlin</td></tr>
  </table>);

  print markdown( $markdown );
  ```

  Text::Markdown will convert the Markdown elements to HTML, while preserving the table.

Comment: thank you for your response, i tried t o use the code you wrote, but here is what i got : Can't locate object method "convert" via package "0" (perhaps you forgot to load "0"?),

Comment: @Mons That sounds surprising (it works fine when I try it). What happens if you replace `pandoc->convert` with `Pandoc::pandoc->convert`?

Comment: same error, i've installed the module with cpanm

Comment: @Mons do you have the pandoc *program* installed too, or just the perl module?

Comment: @Mons: Do you definitely have the `use Pandoc` line in your code?

Comment: actually no, i've just installed the pandoc module of perl, and yes i've used "use Pandoc" as well

Comment: You need the program too.

Comment: @Mons You can install pandoc by doing `sudo apt install pandoc` on Debian/Ubuntu. Not sure for other systems.

Comment: well, we can't use that since we are working on a web app on centos 7

Comment: @Mons `yum install pandoc` should work on CentOS.

Comment: Thank you so much @Dada, your suggestion worked too, very glad you helped me, i really appreciate that <3